# c++ "this" pointer in for_each

Tags: c++, tree, this, functor

I am reading other people' code and this part confuses me. Could any one explain to me what the `*this` refers to here and what this line (`for_each(node->items.begin(), node->items.end(), *this);`) does? This piece of codes comes from searching an element in an R/R* tree. I think here we should provide a functor to `for_each(begin,end,functor)`, but I don't know what `*this` (which seems to me is an element of the "`node->items`" vector) will actually do.

```
// this functor recursively walks the tree
        template <typename Acceptor, typename Visitor>
        struct QueryFunctor : std::unary_function< const BoundedItem, void > {
                const Acceptor &accept;
                Visitor &visitor;

                explicit QueryFunctor(const Acceptor &a, Visitor &v) : accept(a), visitor(v) {}

                void operator()(BoundedItem * item)
                {
                        Node * node = static_cast<Node*>(item);

                        if (visitor.ContinueVisiting && accept(node))
                        {
                                if (node->hasLeaves)
                                        for_each(node->items.begin(), node->items.end(), VisitFunctor<Acceptor, Visitor>(accept, visitor));
                                else
                                        for_each(node->items.begin(), node->items.end(), *this);
                        }
                }
        };
```

Comment: `this` is a pointer to an object, on which the particular method was invoked.

Comment: And `for_each` is part of the standard library, so you can easily search for it online. For example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Comment: i definitely know for_each @FabioTurati

Comment: If you know `for_each`, what is the problem?

Comment: not sure what "*this" refers to in specific here @juanchopanza

Comment: @daydayup I already told you that on my first comment: `this` refers to the object, on which that method was invoked.

Comment: That is something that can also be easily looked up.

Comment: Do you better understand with `QueryFunctor(*this)` or with `QueryFunctor(accept, visitor)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[R* tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree) is a type of R tree with better query performance (but slightly higher construction cost). R tree is a data structure that contains directories (non-ending nodes) and leaves (ending nodes). Member `bool hasLeaves` of a node tells whether the node contains directories (`hasLeaves` is `false`) or leaves (`hasLeaves` is `true`). Directories are just recursively traversed, but leaves are what we are interested in.

When the code calls `for_each(..., *this)` it will call `QueryFunctor::operator()(BoundedItem * item)` for every item in given range. `for_each` can take both a function or an operator() with one given parameter, and in this case it's operator(). Elements of the given range are actually of type `Node*`, but `Node` is derived from `BoundedItem`, so the parameter type match. This is visible in the code you provided in the line with `static_cast`, but for better understanding I read the complete code [here](http://nusoft.fnal.gov/larsoft/doxsvn/html.1.7.1/RStarTree_8h_source.html).